# Anayltic Continuation on complement of countable set

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

I'm reading  Reconstructing a neural net from its output, and there's this remark.

Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be analytic on $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$, with $\Omega_1$ connected and $\mathbb{C} \setminus \Omega_2$ countable. Say $F_1= F_2$ to infinite order at some point in $\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2$. Then $F_1 = F_2$ on $\Omega_1 \cap Omega_2$.

[image]

I do know that by identity theorem, if $F_1 = F_2$ on some $S \subseteq \Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2$, then $F_1 = F_2$. However, I don't know what is meant by "infinite order", so I don't know what the remark is saying.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll make this a comment rather than an answer since I'm not certain, but I believe saying that $f=0$ to infinite order at a point $p_0$ (where here, of course, $f=F_1-F_2$) is saying that not only is $\lim_{p\to p_0}f(p)=0$, but it goes to zero so quickly that $\lim_{p\to p_0}\dfrac{f(p)}{|p-p_0|^n}=0$ for all $n$. One example of such a function would be $e^{-1/x^2}$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki then isn't the "infinite order" part a redundant assumption since you really only need $\lim_{p \to p_0} f(p) = 0$ to have $F_1 = F_2$?

Comment: No, the assumption of infinite order is needed, since you're only assuming $f(p)=0$ (to infinite order) at a **single** point $p\in \Omega_1\cap\Omega_2$ (think $F_1=z^k, F_2=z^l$ so that $f$ vanishes to order $\min\{k,l\}$ at $p=0$, but $f$ is not the zero function). This is a rephrasing of the Riemann identity theorem.

Comment: @Jose27 ah right, we basically need for some $x_n \to x$, $f(x_n) = 0$ for all $n$, which $\lim_{p \to p_0} f(p) = 0$ doesn't guarantee.

Comment: in this context (complex analysis), infinite order usually means that the derivatives of any order are equal at $p$, so $F_1^{(n)}(p)=F_2^{(n)}(p)$ for all $n \ge 0$ (since for any analytic function, we can assign an integral order of vanishing at a point); in a real context, it usually means what @Steven says (since for real functions, we usually cannot assign such an order of vanishing)